# How are lookup fields implemented with a 3rd party framework?

Tags: visualforce, angularjs

I am using Angular for a VisualForce page but would still like to leverage some of the VisualForce components that it provides.

For example I have a lookup bound to an angular variable

```
<apex:inputField value="{!case.Caller__c}" 
      html-ng-model="case.Caller__c" html-ng-change="handleOnChange()"/>
```

but this only returns the name value of the record, not the Id.

Is there anyway to get the Id of the record instead of the name? Or how do most people implement lookup fields within their framework?

Comment: You can try with apex:inputText instead of apex:inputField.

Answer (score 2):

Answering more broadly, I think you'll get nothing but trouble trying to embed AngularJS attributes onto VisualForce elements. That doesn't mean you can't ever use AngularJS on a VF page, but they shouldn't be fighting over the same DOM elements. Also versions of Angular JS from 1.4.x upwards fight with the syntax VisualForce uses to formulate its auto-generated element IDs, which makes it impossible to have any Angular-tagged elements inside an `apex:form`.

VisualForce knows, in the view state, what the actual ID value of that lookup is. But it's not storing it in that DOM element. If you use "Inspect Element" in your browser and watch what happens when you select a new record from the lookup, you'll see that the visible lookup field is one `input` element, but there is also a hidden `input` preceding it with the same ID plus `_lkid`. The value of **that** field is the record ID. But none of the attributes you place on `apex:inputField` are going to flow through to that hidden `input`. So the AngularJS model of passively scanning for updates ain't gonna work here.

Also beware of the use of `rerender` in mixed VF/AngularJS. If VF rerenders a section by AJAX which was previously bound to AngularJS, Angular will not be happy.

Comment: I'm actually moving away from visual force. The requirements for this feature are too complex for visual force.

Comment: Fair enough. FYI the best model for using AngularJS in VF is to use the various available JavaScript Remoting methods. If you're going with Angular in the first place, you don't want VF to construct the DOM for you - that should be Angular's job. VF/Apex should just supply the data for you to render as desired.

Comment: We wrote a pretty dynamic service for using Force Remoting, but if I can save time by using out of the box I really want to leverage that. I'm just going to substitute the lookup with a typeahead.